# css - carousel not displaying on page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have just tried adding a carousel to my template. I copied the code from the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/), but this is what I'm getting:[image: screenshot]

It seems that the carousel classes are being ignored. I don't understand what I did wrong since I copied the code from the documentation. Why am I not getting a carousel? I followed the documentation and for some reason, 
my browser is not displaying the carousel at all. All I get is the picture which is too big. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 /* navbar */

    .navbar-default {
      background-color: #337ab7;
      border-color: #E7E7E7;
    }

    /* Title */

    .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
      color: #777;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
      color: #5E5E5E;
    }

    /* Link */

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
      color: #777;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
      color: #333;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
      color: #555;
      background-color: #E7E7E7;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
      color: #555;
      background-color: #D5D5D5;
    }

    /* Caret */

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret {
      border-top-color: #777;
      border-bottom-color: #777;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:focus .caret {
      border-top-color: #333;
      border-bottom-color: #333;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a .caret,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover .caret,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus .caret {
      border-top-color: #555;
      border-bottom-color: #555;
    }

    /* Mobile version */

    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
      border-color: #DDD;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
      background-color: #DDD;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
      background-color: #CCC;
    }

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
        color: #777;
      }
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
        color: #333;
      }
    }

    .navbar-top {
      padding-left: 150px;
      font-size: 10px;
      width: 92%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .carousel-inner > .item >img{
  min-height :100px;
  max-height : 100px;
  width : 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar mobile navbar-default visible-xs">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-sm-4" style="color:#fff">
            <strong>Cryptocurrencies</strong> 1000 / Markets 1000</div>
          <div class="col-sm-5" style="color:#fff">
            <strong>Market Cap</strong>:$263,920,404,123
            <strong>24h Vol</strong>:$15,360,994,812
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Submit ICO</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Login</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
<div class="container">
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/coins_icons/bt2_.png" alt="First slide]">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" width="100" height="100" src="images/coins_icons/bt2_.png" alt="First slide]">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
       <img class="d-block w-100" width="100" height="100" src="images/coins_icons/bt2_.png" alt="First slide]">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: couple of reasons probably. You didn't include the necessary javascript, the images are probably huge, while you didn't explicitly resized them.

Comment: Just added the JavaScript and resized the images, they are still not scrolling

Answer (score 0):

just put the carousel inside the container will be ok.

```
<div class="container">
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/coins_icons/bt2_.png" alt="First slide]">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/coins_icons/bt2_.png" alt="First slide]">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
       <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/coins_icons/bt2_.png" alt="First slide]">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited my OP and added the container. Now the weird thing is when I set a width and height attribute on my IMG tag, it doesn't resize. Also, my carousel still wont switch images.

Answer (score 0):

you also need the following script to switch the image

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

About the width and height, the class "w-100" or width='100' either work, but you don't need to use these two at the same time